# Export Users in AD with extensionAttribute12

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to export a list of users with their values in the extensionAttribute12 field. I have the command below but the attribute field is blank when I open the CSV.

```
Get-ADUser -Properties extensionAttribute12 -Filter * | Select sAMAccountName, extensionAttribute12 | export-csv c:\temp\extensionattribute12.csv
```

Any ideas on what I need to change so it shows the values?

Comment: and when you dont export to csv is the value displayed in the console?

Comment: Yes it shows the value in the console, should I add something like -NoTypeInformation ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADUser -Properties extensionAttribute12 -Filter * | Select sAMAccountName, extensionAttribute12 | export-csv c:\temp\extensionattribute12.csv -NoTypeInformation
```